# Why aren't my tags properly closed?

Tags: android, tags, tagging

I have a 2 days Android experience...
What is wrong about the tagging in this layout?
It says tag start is not closed but I don't have to close every TextView with `/>`, right?

The tutorial guy said you need to put only one `/>` at the end?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:text="Happy Birthday Mert"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
<TextView
    android:text="from cengiz"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/cake"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

every tag in xml has to closed. in your case both textview has to be closed like this.

```
<TextView
    android:text="from cengiz"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

or like this

```
<TextView
    android:text="from cengiz"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

`I don't have to close every TextView with /> right?`
Of course, **you have to**!

`The tutorial guy said you need to put only one /> at the end?`
I really doubt programmer would say so.

This

```
<TextView
    android:text="Happy Birthday Mert"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
<TextView
    android:text="from cengiz"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

**must** be

```
<TextView
    android:text="Happy Birthday Mert"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<TextView
    android:text="from cengiz"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```